# Adding multiple key-value pairs to groovy map

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create map with multiple key-value pairs, and later based on user's input retrieve corresponding `testInput`. I am after direct key access. I do not want to scan entire map.

Here is my logic:

```
properties([
  [
    $class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions:
    [
      [
        $class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
        choices    : 'qa\ndev\nstg\nprod',
        description: 'environment',
        name       : 'USERPARAM'
      ]
    ]
  ]
])
def selectedBuildParam = "${params.USERPARAM}"
Map configurations = [
        [ buildParam: "qa", testInput: "--tags @qa -p qa" ],
        [ buildParam: "dev", testInput: "--tags @stg --tags -p dev"],
        [ buildParam: "stg", testInput: "--tags @stg --tags 'not @smoke' -p stg"],
        [ buildParam: "prod", testInput: "--tags @prod -p prod"]
]
def testInput = configurations[selectedBuildParam].testInput
```

Can I do something like this in Groovy?
Or use something like:

```
[ "qa": "--tags @qa -p qa" ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like so:

```
Map configurations = [
        [ "qa": "--tags @qa -p qa" ],
        [ "dev": "--tags @stg --tags -p dev"],
        [ "stg": "--tags @stg --tags 'not @smoke' -p stg"],
        [ "prod": "--tags @prod -p prod"]
]
def testInput = configurations[selectedBuildParam]
```